# Nginx reverse proxy for WSO2 API manager devportal/publisher portal not authenticating

Tags: nginx, wso2, wso2-api-manager, nginx-reverse-proxy

I followed this article [Setup WSO2 with NGINX Reverse Proxy for custom URLs](https://techglimpse.com/wso2-nginx-reverse-proxy-custom-url/) to setup the reverse proxy.

Whenever I hit the publisher or developer portal authentication endpoint getting the following error in wso2 logs.

```
2023-07-19 09:52:11,530] ERROR - [idp] Servlet.service() for servlet [idp] in context with path [/publisher] threw exception
java.io.IOException: An exception occurred processing [/services/login/idp.jsp] at line [71]

68:     HttpRequest getSettingsReq = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
69:             .uri(URI.create(settingsAPIUrl))
70:             .build();
71:     HttpResponse<String> settingsResult = client.send(getSettingsReq, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
72: 
73:     HttpRequest getCatalogReq = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
74:             .uri(URI.create(serviceCatalogSettingsAPIUrl))


Stacktrace:
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:494) ~[tomcat_9.0.70.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:379) ~[tomcat_9.0.70.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:327) ~[tomcat_9.0.70.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779) ~[tomcat-servlet-api_9.0.70.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat_9.0.70.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat_9.0.70.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat_9.0.70.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat_9.0.70.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat_9.0.70.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(ContentTypeBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:53) ~[org.wso2.carbon.ui_4.8.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat_9.0.70.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat_9.0.70.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126) ~[tomcat_9.0.70.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat_9.0.70.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat_9.0.70.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177) ~[tomcat_9.0.70.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat_9.0.70.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat_9.0.70.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat_9.0.70.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat_9.0.70.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:119) ~[org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve_1.7.1.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.OrganizationContextRewriteValve.invoke(OrganizationContextRewriteValve.java:116) ~[org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve_1.7.1.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.SameSiteCookieValve.invoke(SameSiteCookieValve.java:38) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.8.1.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:165) ~[org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve_1.7.1.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:111) ~[org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve_1.7.1.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:106) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.8.1.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.8.1.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:67) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.8.1.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:152) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.8.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687) ~[tomcat_9.0.70.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:63) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.8.1.jar:?]
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.RequestCorrelationIdValve.invoke(RequestCorrelationIdValve.java:137) ~[org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext_4.8.1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat_9.0.70.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat_9.0.70.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat_9.0.70.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat_9.0.70.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:891) ~[tomcat_9.0.70.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1784) ~[tomcat_9.0.70.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat_9.0.70.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat_9.0.70.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat_9.0.70.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat_9.0.70.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative DNS name matching ****.****.com found.
    at jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.send(HttpClientImpl.java:578) ~[java.net.http:?]
    at jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientFacade.send(HttpClientFacade.java:123) ~[java.net.http:?]
    at org.apache.jsp.services.login.idp_jsp._jspService(idp_jsp.java:203) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) ~[tomcat_9.0.70.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779) ~[tomcat-servlet-api_9.0.70.wso2v1.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:466) ~[tomcat_9.0.70.wso2v1.jar:?]
    ... 42 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative DNS name matching ****.****.com found.
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:378) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:321) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:316) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:654) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1277) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1264) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1209) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate.lambda$executeTasks$3(SSLFlowDelegate.java:1118) ~[java.net.http:?]
    at jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl$DelegatingExecutor.execute(HttpClientImpl.java:157) ~[java.net.http:?]
    at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate.executeTasks(SSLFlowDelegate.java:1113) ~[java.net.http:?]
    at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate.doHandshake(SSLFlowDelegate.java:1079) ~[java.net.http:?]
    at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader.processData(SSLFlowDelegate.java:484) ~[java.net.http:?]
    at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader$ReaderDownstreamPusher.run(SSLFlowDelegate.java:268) ~[java.net.http:?]
    at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$LockingRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:205) ~[java.net.http:?]
    at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$CompleteRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:149) ~[java.net.http:?]
    at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:230) ~[java.net.http:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[?:?]
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching ****.****.com found.
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchDNS(HostnameChecker.java:212) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:103) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:458) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:418) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:292) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:144) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:632) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.onCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:473) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.consume(CertificateMessage.java:369) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:396) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:480) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1277) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask$DelegatedAction.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1264) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712) ~[?:?]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl$DelegatedTask.run(SSLEngineImpl.java:1209) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[?:?]
    at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate.lambda$executeTasks$3(SSLFlowDelegate.java:1118) ~[java.net.http:?]
    at jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl$DelegatingExecutor.execute(HttpClientImpl.java:157) ~[java.net.http:?]
    at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate.executeTasks(SSLFlowDelegate.java:1113) ~[java.net.http:?]
    at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate.doHandshake(SSLFlowDelegate.java:1079) ~[java.net.http:?]
    at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader.processData(SSLFlowDelegate.java:484) ~[java.net.http:?]
    at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SSLFlowDelegate$Reader$ReaderDownstreamPusher.run(SSLFlowDelegate.java:268) ~[java.net.http:?]
    at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$LockingRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:205) ~[java.net.http:?]
    at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$CompleteRestartableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:149) ~[java.net.http:?]
    at jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:230) ~[java.net.http:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[?:?]
```

[error in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kX0LQ.png)
Getting the 404 error when i click login button.

Am I missing some configuration? Is there any better way to setup reverse proxy for wso2 other than this.?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No subject alternative DNS name matching ****.****.com found.` which means you don't have a certificate that has the `****.****.com` as the CN or SAN in your client trustore. Assuming you have created the certificates properly with the correct CNs try importing the NginX Public cert to WSO2's clinet-trustore.